# How to show front end ACF field from user profile?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to echo an ACF value on the frontend woocommerce My Account page. The value is stored against a user account. The only problem i'm having is getting the value from the current logged in user.

I've got the following code which should work according to http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/ should work.

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 
$number = "user_$user_ID";
the_field('domain_name', $number); ?>
```

But it doesn't! As soon as i remove the

```
$number = "user_$user_ID";
```

and replace it with

```
$number = "user_3";
```

it works perfectly....but this is a hardcoded value, rather than calling the current user ID

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be forming the $number like this:

```
$number = "user_".$user_ID;
```

Comment: Have you tried `the_field('domain_name', 'user_'.$user_ID)`

Comment: Also have you tried `echo $user_ID;` to make sure its returning a value?

Comment: Yes it's definately returning a value, and just tried the second thing, but still no luck

Comment: Silly question but is that field filled in for your user account?

Comment: Ok as a last resort try this:
the_field('domain_name', 'user_'.get_current_user_id())

Comment: Still no luck @rich - I've reached out to their techincal support team to see what they think, I'll post an answer once they've got back to me

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 
$number = 'user_' . $user_ID;
the_field('domain_name', $number); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo 'User ID: ' . $user->user_ID . "<br>";
```